# I'm trying to display the total amount of lower case letters in a text file, but

Tags: python

I've got the text file for the Dracula novel and I want to count the number of lower case letters contained within it. The code I've got executes without a problem but prints out 4297. I'm not sure where I went wrong and hoped you guys could point out my issue here. Thank you!

Indentation isn't necessarily reflective of what I see on my text editor

```
def main():

        book_file = open('dracula.txt', 'r')
        lower_case = sum(map(str.islower, book_file))   

        print (lower_case)  

    book_file.close()
main()
```

expected: 621607
results: 4297

Comment: So what do you want? Capital letters or small letters?

Comment: My bad. Just edited title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a file, you get a *line* as a value on each iteration. Your current code would be correct if it was running on *characters*, not lines. When you call `islower` on a longer string (like a line from a book), it only returns `True` if all the letters in the string are lowercase.

In your copy of Dracula, there are apparently 4297 lines that contain no capital letters, so that's the result you're getting. The much larger number is the count of characters.

You can fix your code by adding an extra step to read the file as a single large string, the iterating on that.

```
def main():
    with open('dracula.txt', 'r') as book_file:
        text = book_file.read()
    lower_case = sum(map(str.islower, text))
    print(lower_case)
```

I also modified your code slightly by using a `with` statement to handle closing the file. This is nice because it will *always* close the file when it exits the intended block, even if something has gone wrong and an exception has been raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to count the lower-case and upper-case characters

```
import re

text = "sdfsdfdTTsdHSksdsklUHD"

lowercase = len(re.findall("[a-z]", text))
uppercase = len(re.findall("[A-Z]", text))

print(lowercase)
print(uppercase)
```

Outputs:

```
15 
7
```

And you will need to change how you read the file to

```
text = open("dracula.txt").read()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help as well

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('dracula.txt', 'r') as book_file:
   count=0 
   for line in book_file: # for each line in the file you will count the number # of lower case letters and add it to the variable "count"
      count+=sum(map(str.islower, line))  

print("number of lower case letters = " +int(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses a list comprehension rather than `map()`

It iterates over the characters in the text and creates a list of all lowercase characters.  The length of this list is the number of lowercase letters in the text.

```
with open('dracula.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
lowers = [char for char in text if char.islower()]
print(len(lowers))
```

Comment: Appreciate the extra input. Helps me see different ways to tackle this issue